# Mongoose Query selecting parent and only matched children

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im having trouble query this type of data

```
[
{ev:1,
image:[{id:24,name:'ads1'},{id:25,name:'ads2'},{id:26,name:'ads4'},{id:27,name:'ads3'}]
 },
{ev:1,
image:[{id:29,name:'ads1'},{id:23,name:'ads2'},{id:34,name:'ads4'},{id:50,name:'ads3'}]
 }
 ]
```

this is my query

```
 var data =  schema.find( {

             $and: [
              {
               ev: 1
              },
              {
               'image.id': {
                $in: [26,29,50,34]
               }
              }
             ]
            
           } , 'ev image'  )
```

what result i need is

```
[
{ev:1,
image:[{id:26,name:'ads4'}]
 },
{ev:1,
image:[{id:29,name:'ads1'},{id:34,name:'ads4'}, {id:50,name:'ads3'}]
 }
 ]
```

Im using moongose

but i keep getting back the whole image array

i basically need the image object filtered with only the image.id  i want

PS there are more ev 1,2,3.... hence i need to only find in the ev i provide

could someone please help me with this

**im new to mongodb**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find is used to keep or reject complete documents(find has a project also but in general for transformations we use aggregate operators).
The bellow is aggregation that keeps only part of the array.

Query

- match the `ev=1`
- filter the image and keep only those that are contained in the the array `[26, 29, 50, 34]`
- if you want you can add another match to filter out the documents with empty array (no id was member of the array)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=624f188cf7e3c64c6511e16b)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"ev": {"$eq": 1}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"image": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$image",
        "cond": {"$in": ["$$this.id", [26, 29, 50, 34]]}}}}}])
```

Comment: hey its working could you show me how to  filter the empty array .... sorry for the trouble. trying to learn it

Comment: try [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=624f32c6f7e3c64c6511e16c) its like the above with one extra match stage in the end `{"$match": {"$expr": {"$ne": ["$image", []]}}}`